# Clojure function to print symbol name and symbol value

Tags: clojure

I have been struggling to find an answer or develop a solution.  I am trying to figure out how to make code that makes code in Clojure.  For my first feat, I want a function that will print to stdout the name of the symbol and its value, useful for debugging.  Example:

```
(def mysymbol 5)
(debugging-function mysymbol)

mysymbol: 5
```

Does that make sense?  Thanks for your help.

**Post Discussion Update**

Here is the answer from @amalloy:

```
(defmacro ?
"A useful debugging tool when you can't figure out what's going on:
wrap a form with ?, and the form will be printed alongside
its result. The result will still be passed along."
[val]
`(let [x# ~val]
    (prn '~val '~'is x#)
    x#))
```

So:
`(? myvariable)`

Comment: Seems a bit weird to copy my answer into your question. That will probably discourage other people from coming up with alternative answers, since it becomes unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: @amalloy, I agree, but then again, there is no code in your answer!

Comment: @amalloy I edited the question to clear this up.

Comment: Thank you for help out this new user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see a simple version of this that I wrote [on github](https://github.com/amalloy/amalloy-utils/blob/master/src/amalloy/utils/debug.clj). The main point is that you can't do this with a function, but with a macro it's simple enough - you just have to get your quoting and unquoting right.

Comment: You were fast and spot on!  No wonder I couldn't get it right.  Your code is beyond my comprehension at the moment, but I am going to figure out how it works.